# Sending authenticated mail using SmtpClient

Tags: c#, wireshark, credentials, smtpclient

I want to send an email using c# SmtpClient via an smtp host that requires authentication or it will fail with relay denied. I have read many posts, but none quite solve my issue which is that while I specify NetworkCredentials, in the communication with the mailhost, no credentials are passed along. This confuses me.

This is the code that sets the credential and sends the mail:

```
            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = smtpserver,
                Port = port,
                EnableSsl = ssl
            })
            {
                if (username.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Setting credentials to\nusername: {0}\npassword: {1}", username, password);
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                }
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
```

The correct credentials are printed to the console.

This is the TCP stream as captured by Wireshark:

```
220 mail.myhost.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 20 Jan 2015 12:44:19 +0100
EHLO DK-XYZ-800SFF1
250-mail.myhost.com Hello [172.16.123.132]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
MAIL FROM:<myemail@myhost.dk>
250 2.1.0 Sender OK
RCPT TO:<someemail@gmail.com>
550 5.7.1 Unable to relay
```

Clearly no authentication attempts are being made, despite the credentials having been set on SmtpClient.

Comment: ARE the credentials being set? Because they are only set when the username.Length is longer than zero characters.

Comment: As I wrote, the correct credentials are being printed to the console and are therefore being set.

Comment: My bad. Sorry. Did you set a breakpoint and inspected the Credentials property of the smtp object. Are they properly being set there?

Comment: The Credentials object is present and has the correct information. Just checked. I wonder if the smtp server requires a special form for authentication details? I am not familiar with the smtp server keywords and how to match it with SmtpClient.

Comment: You probably need to set UseDefaultCredentials to true, see; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Copied from your link: "Set this property to true when this SmtpClient object should, if requested by the server, authenticate using the default credentials of the currently logged on user. ". This is not what I need. I need to enter my own email credentials, not my windows credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue and learned a bit in the process. While my code was correct, one of the parameters that I did not provide was the port information. From the SMTP log above, we can see the AUTH line is empty, i.e. has no protocols available for authentication. That is why SmtpClient didn't send any credentials.

The reason why AUTH line didn't have any methods for authentication was because I was using port 25 for communication. As soon as I switched to port 587, smtp reported that authentication was possible and credentials were sent and mails were sent as intended.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static void CreateTestMessage2(string server)
    {
                string to = "jane@contoso.com";
                string from = "ben@contoso.com";
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
                message.Subject = "Using the new SMTP client.";
            message.Body = @"Using this new feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
            // Credentials are necessary if the server requires the client  
            // to authenticate before it will send e-mail on the client's behalf.
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

      try {
              client.Send(message);
            }  
            catch (Exception ex) {
              Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateTestMessage2(): {0}", 
                    ex.ToString() );              
      }              
        }`
```

Comment: There are no credentials given so I wonder why this would work. But I tried it and it failed.

Comment: The OP's example clearly shows he is not using default credentials, so this answer is incorrect and irrelevant.